# Qt - how to uncompress and compress tar , zip , lz4 on Qt 5.10.1?

Tags: qt, compression

sorry for my english.
I use **Qt 5.10.1** and i want uncompress ***tar , zip , lz4*** formats and compress. please help me, thank you

Comment: There is no such functionality in qt.

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't do this for you. You need to link in the appropriate libraries and use their functions:

- [libtar](http://repo.or.cz/w/libtar.git)
- [libzip](https://nih.at/libzip)
- [lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4)

Qt does have a [zlib Compression Library](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtcore-attribution-zlib.html)

Comment: i need help more. give me example or tutorial for above problem